# How does aging affect fingerprint?

Tags: human-anatomy, development, growth

Do fingerprints change as we grow from child to adult? Most notably, what is the effect of the increase in surface area of palms and fingers on the finger print? Does the finger print simply increases in size, and/or does the pattern change?

And what about old age? As the connective tissue in dermis get lax, how is the fingerprint affected?

Comment: All the evidence I found says that fingerprints do not change over time. However, I also found a paper from the National Academy of Science of America, which concluded that there is not peer-reviewed scientific report on fingerprints and if and how they possibly change over time. I think this question cannot be answered right now.

Answer (score 1):

Fingerprints form in the womb at 22 weeks and after that, all they will do is expand as you grow. Therefore, it is possible that a fingerprint 22 weeks after conception could be used to identify a 50-year-old criminal.

Comment: can you please add a source?

Comment: Can you add some references to your answer?